# How to make python matplotlib display x-axis coordinates (right corner) when x-axis is a string

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I use plt to draw a chart, if the x-axis is a string, the coordinates in the lower right corner cannot be displayed.

This will only appear in ubuntu. If I use windows, there will be no problem.

I hope that x can show the value so that I can find the corresponding date in a large chart. What should I do?

Thanks for your help

lib: matplotlib             3.1.2

os: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

code:

```
        x = ["2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-04"]
        y = [1, 2, 3, 4]
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
        ax.plot(x, y)
        plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: matplotlib 3.1.2 is extremely old. Your first step should be upgrading.

Comment: @JohanC many thanks. When I upgraded to 3.4.2, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

When I upgraded to 3.4.2, the problem was solved.
Thanks @JohanC